# ImageMagick command to convert and save with same name

Tags: shell, imagemagick

I am using ImageMagick **convert** command for making thumbnails & save the converted images in another directory, one by one, in PHP.

But, cant figure out how to keep the the image name in the converted image.

```
> convert 1.JPG -resize 120X120 thumb/*.JPG
```

need to keep the output file names same as the input. Please help.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

A simple solution would be copy, followed by mogrify - another imagemagick tool - this will keep the same names, it takes all the same args as convert.

```
cp *.jpg thumb/
cd thumb
mogrify -resize 120X120 *.JPG
```

Alternatively you could do a bit of shell scripting, using find -exec or xargs

```
# using -exec
find . -iname "*.JPG" -maxdepth 1 -exec convert -resize 120x120 {} thumbs/{} \;

# using xargs
find . -iname "*.JPG" -maxdepth 1 | xargs -i{} convert -resize 120x120 {} thumbs/{}
```

Comment: thanx man. it worked. Will check out the exec & xargs also.
thanks again.

Answer (score 41):

Another way:

```
convert *.jpg -resize 80% -set filename:f '%t' ../'%[filename:f].jpg'
```

Will place converted files in the folder above.

The option `-set filename:f '%t'` sets the property `filename:f` to the current filename without the extension. Properties beginning with `filename:` are a special case that can be referenced in the output filename. Here we set it to `../'%[filename:f].jpg`, which ends up being the image filename with the extension replaced with `.jpg` in the parent directory.

#### Documentation references:

- [`-set` documentation](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#set), which mentions the `filename:` special case
- [`%t` and other Format and Print Image Properties](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/escape.php)

Comment: For some reason, this doesn't work for me when the output is `.webp`.

Comment: This should work indeed, but also in my case doesn't work (Windows 11, WebP); it instead just creates a single big file.

Answer (score 7):

Another easy way that doesn't involve a lot of typing is [GNU Parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/):

```
parallel convert {} -resize 120X120 thumb/{} ::: *.jpg
```

`convert` is called for each of the files given after `:::`, and `{}` is replaced with the file name for each invokation. This will also process the files in parallel, so it's likely a lot faster than the other solutions here.

It also works if you want to convert the file type:

```
parallel convert {} {.}.png ::: *.jpg
```

`{.}` is replaced with the filename without extension, allowing you to change it easily.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I do:

Convert all files to `filename-new.extension`

```
for FILE in *; do convert -resize 320 $FILE $(echo $FILE | sed 's/\./-new./'); done
```

Move all `filename-new.extension` files back to `filename.extension`:

```
for FILE in *; do mv $FILE $(echo $FILE | sed 's/-new//'); done
```

Answer (score 0):

In Windows, do this instead:

```
FOR /f "tokens=*" %G IN ('dir /b *.jpg') DO convert %G -resize 120x120 thumb\%G
```

Notes:

- Make sure you create the `thumb` folder in advance.
- Use `%%` intead of `%`, if you make this part of a batch (.bat) file.
- A benefit over doing it all at once with one `convert` is that this is more memory efficient, *probably*..